# perl regex: negative lookahead between two characters

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

How would you include a pattern between two characters in a regular expression?

Say i wanted to print everything in the below text apart from words in between `" "`

```
This is an "example".

This "is" "an" example.

"This" is an example.
```

This is what I've tried so far, but i think I'm missing something:

```
m/(?!"(.*)").*/g
```

Comment: What about nested quotes? And are you wanting to print the punctuation also or just `words`?

Comment: Just tried it and it it seem to group everything correctly now:http://regex101.com/r/sZ8xG0 but i still cant negate anything between quotes when i try to add ?! : (.*)((")(?!(.*))(")).*

Comment: The question isn't quite clear but it seems that you are looking for `'s/"[^"]*"//g'`

Comment: You have to anchor a negative lookaround assertion, or it will just move until it does match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'This "is" "an" example';
@words = ($s =~ /"([^"]*)"/g);
```

`@words` contains all words between `" "`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `s///` to remove those substrings between double quotes.

Here is a test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(switch say);

use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/"[^"]*"//g;
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
This is an "example".
This "is" "an" example.
"This" is an example.
```

---

Result:

```
$ perl t.pl
This is an .
This   example.
 is an example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to redraiment's solution:

```
@words_in_quotes = ($s =~ /"(.*?)"/g)
```

No need for look-behind assertions.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the definition of an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Assertions are sort of an advanced feature of regular expressions, and most likely not going to be needed for the majority of problems you'd have to solve.

Instead, I'd focus on the basics, probably starting with greedy versus non-greedy matching.

```
@quoted_words = ($s =~ /"(.*?)"/g);
```

Anytime, you use a quantifier `*` or `+`, it will attempt to match as many as possible and then work it's way back.  You limit this by either reducing the types of characters it should match and adding boundary conditions, or by changing the matching to be non-greedy by adding a question mark.  `*?` or `+?`